# [Odoo][v10] Add subscription types for a follower from Python in Odoo v10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I building my own module, and for each project, I add a calendar event with followers from the project.

So i write a method:

```
def create_calendar_event(self):
    create_event = self.env['calendar.event'].create({'start': self.start_date, 'stop': self.end_date, 'name': self.title})
    self.calendar_id = create_event

    partner_list = []
    for follower in self.project_id.message_follower_ids:
        partner_list.append(follower.partner_id.id)
    self.testfield = str(partner_list)  #   Debug

    calendar_fallowers = []
    for follower2 in self.calendar_id.message_follower_ids:
        calendar_fallowers.append(follower2.partner_id.id)
    self.testfield_calendar = str(calendar_fallowers)  #   Debug

    #   add followers from project to calendar
    for partner in partner_list:
        if partner not in calendar_fallowers:
            res_id = self.calendar_id.id
            res_model = 'calendar.event'
            partner_id = partner
            self.env['mail.followers'].create({'res_id': res_id, 'res_model': res_model, 'partner_id': partner_id})


    self.env.cr.commit()
```

So I have calendar event with followers, but I don't have any default subscription types.

and I wanna add default  subscription types for all followers: Discussions and Note

How to do this?

Comment: to add followers odoo provide a method for :  `self.calendar_id.message_subscribe(partner_list)` I think use it is better

Comment: and please never ever commit by yourself, unless it is really necessary

Comment: @CZoellner why don't commit by myself ?

Comment: Because Odoo is doing it already but rollbacking if necessary. You're probably undergoing the whole commit/rollback chain of the ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add followers odoo provide a method for :

```
   self.calendar_id.message_subscribe(partner_list)
```

And to remove folowers :

```
   some_record.message_unsubscribe(partner_list)
```